# How to deploy docker image on kubernetes using jenkins x

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, jenkins-x

I have created kubernetes cluster using minikube. I am able to build an docker image using jenkins x but how can I deploy that image on kubernets. I am trying to install than image using helm `sh "helm install -n go-k8s ./go-k8s/helm-chart"` but it is  showing error `helm: not found`
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is all done inside a `Jenkinsfile` right? By default Jenkins X creates build pods which have tools like `helm`, `kubectl` or `jx` inside - so you need to run those binary tools inside `container('foo') {...` block which is what the default pipelines do.

How about you [create a quickstart via `jx`](https://jenkins-x.io/developing/create-quickstart/) and then you'll get a working `Jenkinsfile` that builds a docker image, releases a helm chart and then promotes it through your environments - and generates a Preview Environment on each Pull Request to verify changes before you merge.

You can then copy/paste the `Jenkinsfile` and use it for you other project?

Comment: Yes, its all done using jenkinsfile but I am trying simple command `sh 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces'` , it is showing error `kubectl not found`. As I am new to this can you please elaborate how to use `container('foo') {...` this approach ?

` Thanks

Comment: is your `sh` inside a `container(...)` block? BTW its good to use the quickstarts then you get a pipeline that just works OOTB - figuring these out by hand takes lots of time and its really undifferentiated heavy lifting